# Getting a value in a complicated R object (ltm package)

Tags: r, object

This R code adjusts a 2-PL IRT model and calculates the parameters "difficulty" and "discrimination":

```
library("ltm")
library("difR")

data(verbal, package = "difR")
dat <- verbal[, 1:24]
res_2pl <- ltm(dat ~ z1)
res_2pl
```

This is the output:

```
Coefficients:
             Dffclt  Dscrmn
S1wantCurse  -0.913   1.358
S1WantScold  -0.409   1.525
S1WantShout  -0.078   1.340
…
```

My Question: how can I get the value of the difficulty parameter of variable S1WantScold (i.e. -0.409) so I am able to assign it to a new variable for example?
I think res_2pl$coefficients may contain the coefficients, but I just can't fiddle out how to drill down to the parameter value itself.
Any help much appreciated.

The structure of the object:

```
> str(res_2pl_1)
List of 14
 $ coefficients: num [1:24, 1:2] 1.24 0.623 0.104 1.824 0.784 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:24] "S1wantCurse" "S1WantScold" "S1WantShout" "S2WantCurse" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "z1"
 $ log.Lik     : num -4017
 $ convergence : int 0
 $ hessian     : num [1:48, 1:48] 47.8 -2.23 -1.99 -1.86 -2.27 ...
 $ counts      : Named int [1:2] 17 4
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "function" "gradient"
 $ patterns    :List of 2
  ..$ X  : num [1:303, 1:24] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ obs: int [1:303] 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ GH          :List of 2
  ..$ Z  : num [1:21, 1:2] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ GHw: num [1:21] 2.10e-14 4.98e-11 1.45e-08 1.23e-06 4.22e-05 ...
 $ max.sc      : num 0.0213
 $ ltst        :List of 5
  ..$ factors: int 1
  ..$ inter  : logi FALSE
  ..$ quad.z1: logi FALSE
  ..$ quad.z2: logi FALSE
  ..$ nams   : chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "z1"
 $ X           :'data.frame':   316 obs. of  24 variables:
  ..$ S1wantCurse: int [1:316] 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 ...
  ..$ S1WantScold: int [1:316] 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 ...
  ..$ S1WantShout: int [1:316] 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 ...
  ..$ S2WantCurse: int [1:316] 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 ...
  ..$ S2WantScold: int [1:316] 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 ...
  ..$ S2WantShout: int [1:316] 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 ...
  ..$ S3WantCurse: int [1:316] 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 ...
  
 $ control     :List of 6
  ..$ iter.em : num 40
  ..$ iter.qN : num 150
  ..$ GHk     : num 21
  ..$ method  : chr "BFGS"
  ..$ parscale: NULL
  ..$ verbose : logi FALSE
 $ IRT.param   : logi TRUE
 $ formula     :Class 'formula'  language dat_1 ~ z1
  .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
 $ call        : language ltm(formula = dat_1 ~ z1)
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "ltm"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is a `matrix`

```
str(coef(res_2pl))
 num [1:24, 1:2] -0.913 -0.4087 -0.0777 -1.2427 -0.5001 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:24] "S1wantCurse" "S1WantScold" "S1WantShout" "S2WantCurse" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "Dffclt" "Dscrmn"
```

we can use the dimnames to extract

```
coef(res_2pl)['S1WantScold' ,'Dffclt']
[1] -0.4086988
```